# How to hide div from printing only for prints over a specific link tag with js script?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

The page has to have two print versions. One with price and on without. My solution works in Firefox, but not in chromebased Browser.

What I do:
If the printlink is klicked, I add the `print:hidden-class` name, then print, then remove the class:

```
<a href="javascript:if(window.print){document.getElementById('priceinfo').classList.add('print:hidden'); window.print(); document.getElementById('priceinfo').classList.remove('print:hidden');} ">print without price</a>
```

Why ist this not working in Edge or Chrome? And what will work?

Comment: Don't slap js code into href. Use a <script> tag or a separate javascript file.

Comment: use `media="print"`  --> `<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">` or `<style  media="print">`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Fractalism moving the code into script tags worked:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('#print-no-price').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(window.print) {
      document.getElementById('priceinfo').classList.add('print:hidden'); 
      window.print(); 
      document.getElementById('priceinfo').classList.remove('print:hidden');
    }
  });
</script>
```